# How to detect bluetooth device type?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a provision to know which type of device is discovered? Say whether it is a mobile/laptop/any other device.I have tried with BluetoothDevice.getType(), but this provides an integer value 1 in all cases(mobile,laptop,etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the people who have down voted, it would be easy if you tell the reason why you do so. So that I can avoid repeating the fault on my next post. I haven't found any similar questions on search. Also I hope I have explained clearly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getBluetoothClass` it will return different values for phone and computer/laptop